# SIM selection while sending a message

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display sim card selection dialog while sending message from android application.
Please help me to display and choose SIM card.

Comment: If you want help show us your actual code and tell us which is your problem!

Comment: SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(0);
                smsManager.getSubscriptionId();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(toPhoneNumber, null, smsMessage, null, null);

Answer (score 0):

> Use SubscriptionManager for Detecting and and Sending messages using
>   Specified Sim
>
> for mobile Api level above 22

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html